# 2 dimensional loop doesn't work as expected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this loop:

```py
i = 0
j = 1
size = 4

for i in range(i, i + size):
    for j in range(j, j + size):
        print(i, j)
```

I expected it to have the following output:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 1
1 2
. .
. .
. .
3 4
```

But I get this instead:

```
0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
0 4 
1 4 
1 5 
1 6 
1 7 
2 7 
2 8 
2 9 
2 10
3 10
3 11
3 12
3 13
```

It's like the value of `j` is being updated after each outer loop iteration. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please copy the actual output here as text rather than a link to an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting variable initially and using variables with the same name in the loop... use variable with different names in the loop like `a` and `b`:

```
i = 0
j = 1
size = 4

for a in range(i, i + size):
    for b in range(j, j + size):
        print(a, b)

0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
```

Comment: @AllanJuan The lesson here: don't use the same variable name for two different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> It's like the value of j is being updated after each outer loop iteration. Why is this happening?

This is because you set the value of `j` with `for j in range(j, j + size)`. In other words, `j` is set to a new value each time the inner loop iterates. Similarly, you set `i` to a new value each time the outer loop iterates just like you see in the output.

Comment: @AllanJuan So you are reusing a variable for two different purposes: i is both an input and a loop counter. This is a code smell. You should use a separate variable name for each purpose. Similarly with `j`.